# Get Glyphs of a character without using fallback font

Tags: swift, fonts, core-text, glyph, textkit

I'm trying to get CGPath from glyphs for all the fonts available on my iPad, in a few cases the Glyphs are not available for fonts such as "**AcademyEngravedLetPlain**" which looks like below:

[image]

My code:

```
    let attributes = text.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
    let font = attributes[.font] as! UIFont
    //or you can use let font = UIFont(name: "AcademyEngravedLetPlain", size: 30)!

    let unicodeScalarRange: ClosedRange<Unicode.Scalar> = "!" ... "~"
    let unicodeScalarValueRange: ClosedRange<UInt32> = unicodeScalarRange.lowerBound.value ... unicodeScalarRange.upperBound.value
    let unicodeScalarArray: [Unicode.Scalar] = unicodeScalarValueRange.compactMap(Unicode.Scalar.init)

    var a: [UniChar] = unicodeScalarValueRange.map(UniChar.init)
    var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeatElement(0, count: a.count))
    let gotGlyphs = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, &a, &glyphs, a.count)
    if gotGlyphs{
        for g in glyphs {
            if let cgpath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, g, nil) {
                print("cgpath available")
            }
        }
    }else{
        print("Could not get glyphs for font characters!!! No cgpath")
    }
```

How do I get the missing glyphs/paths of the fonts, I don't want to use the **fallback** font. what can be the solution?

Comment: If the glyph does not exist, what do you expect the path to be? Not every font contains every glyph. (Or is there something else you're asking here?)

Comment: @RobNapier but the font is rendered on the screen right? How is that? are those images? the image I attached is from the font menu/font picker and based on this reference every font will have a path: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2274038&seqNum=13

Answer (score 1):

Fonts do not generally have glyphs for every possible character. Some of these characters have glyphs in this font and some do not. The return value of [`CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1510813-ctfontgetglyphsforcharacters#) is only true if every requested character has a glyph. If any of them are missing, it stores 0 in the glyph array at that index, and returns false.

If you change your loop to the following, you can get a list of what's missing for this font:

```
for (c, g) in zip(unicodeScalarArray, glyphs) {
    if g == 0 {
        print("cgpath NOT available for: \(c)")
    }
    else if let cgpath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, g, nil) {
        // print("cgpath available for: \(c)")
    }
}

=>

cgpath NOT available for: #
cgpath NOT available for: +
cgpath NOT available for: <
cgpath NOT available for: =
cgpath NOT available for: >
cgpath NOT available for: @
cgpath NOT available for: ^
cgpath NOT available for: {
cgpath NOT available for: |
cgpath NOT available for: }
cgpath NOT available for: ~
```

Comment: can we create the glyphs by ourselves and link to these fonts(More like Custom fonts), is that possible to do? I don't know about this so I'm asking you.

Comment: That would be a cascade list (what you called a fallback). Create a new font with extra glyphs and add it to the cascade list immediately after the font in question using a UIFontDescriptor. Alternately, you could edit the font to add the glyphs and load your version as a custom font. In both cases there may be copyright issues to investigate with your lawyer. Designing new glyphs is not a simple skill. You probably want to look at TypeTool (https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/typetool/) or FontForge (https://fontforge.org/en-US/).

Comment: You can also use TextKit2. For example, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/textkit/display_text_with_a_custom_layout for discussion of how to draw replacement glyphs in an NSTextContainer. In my experience, this works pretty well, but the system is a bit buggy (at least the last time I was working with it), and if you do anything too unusual, even if the docs suggest it's legal, it can crash. I would explore https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/STTextView since Marcin has done a lot of exploration of this space.

Comment: Thanks for the resources Rob, I think it is better not to go to the extent of Copyright infringement, best to talk to my client instead.